# Is there a way to speed up these nested loops (Laplacian case) Python?

Tags: python, performance, loops, nested-loops

I am trying to speed up the nested loop in my function Gram.

My function that is causing a big delay is the Laplacian (Abel) because it requires to calculate for each cell of the matrix the norm of a column by a row.

`abel = lambda x,y,t,p: np.exp(-np.abs(p) * np.linalg.norm(x-y))`

```
def Gram(X,Y,function,t,p):
    n = X.shape[0]
    s = Y.shape[0]
    K = np.zeros((n,s))
    if function==abel:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(s):
                K[i,j] = abel(X[i,:],Y[j,:],t,p)
    else:
        K = polynomial(X,Y,t,p)
    return K
```

I was able to speed up the function a bit by keeping the exponential part out of the abel equation and then I apply it for the whole matrix.

`abel_2 = lambda x,y,t,p: np.linalg.norm(x-y)` (don't mind the t and p).

```
def Gram_2(X,Y,function,t,p):
    n = X.shape[0]
    s = Y.shape[0]
    K = np.zeros((n,s))
    if function==abel_2:
        for i in range(n):
            for j in range(s):
                K[i,j] = abel_2(X[i,:],Y[j,:],0,0)
        K = np.exp(-abs(p)*K)
    else:
        K = polynomial(X,Y,t,p)
    return K
```

The time is reduced by 50%, however, the double loops (nested) are still a major problem, I believe.
Can someone help with this?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, instead of going through the loops one by one to subtract `X[i,:]` from `Y[j,:]`, it would save tons of time of just selecting `X[i,:]` and subtracting it from all Y, then applying the norm on a certain axis!

In my case it was `axis=1`.

```
def Gram_10(X,Y,function,t,p):
    n = X.shape[0]
    s = Y.shape[0]
    K = np.zeros((n,s))
    if function==abel_2:
        for i in range(n):
# it is important to put the correct slice (:s) , so the matrix provided by the norm goes
# to the right place in the function 
                K[i,:s] = np.linalg.norm(X[i,:]-Y,axis=1)
        K = np.exp(-abs(p)*K)
    else:
        K = polynomial(X,Y,t,p)
    return K
```